# zk-SNARKs: High level language options?

Tags: zksnark, zero-knowledge

I would like to implement an idea that requires me to use a zero knowledge proof. What options do I currently have, assuming I want (need, due to lacking cryptography knowledge) to use a high level language? Documentation is currently lacking and it's hard to get up to date information on what the landscape looks like.

Comment: Is the question about zk-SNARKS as mentioned in title ? If you could provide little more clarity about what you are trying to do and whether it is in the context of ethereum, other contributers can give specific answers.

Comment: @shonjs yes, I have a scheme that would require me to use a snark to verify a computation on chain simply because it'd be too expensive to compute using the EVM. What I am asking is (given how finicky SNARKs are and how much a problem needs to be massaged to be expressed as a SNARK) what is the most high level language that exists today for creating SNARKs, ie the least math-heavy and maximally regular-programming-like. I am currently looking at ZoKrates and it looks fairly workable, but are there any others I should be aware of?